F# FSharp.Core WebExtensions Module
If I get it right, the examples in FSharp.Core WebExtensions Module  use obsolete classes like WebRequest and WebClient and should be using HttpClient instead.
https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-webextensions.html
If this is the case, how to ask to update the examples. I don't see any feedback option on the page.

you can raise an issue in their repo: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/
